# How to loop elements in 2d array to construct an string in "Ruby functional Style"

Tags: java, ruby, functional-programming, ruby-1.9.3

Ruby use the functions from "functional concept" heavily, such as **map, each**.   They really depend on a  **self-contained function** which is so called **block** in Ruby.

It is very common to loop though a 2d array, make an string about the elements.

In java, it may looks like

```
   public String toString(){
        String output = "[";
        for (int i =0; i<array.length; i++) {
            output+= "Row "+(i+1)+" : ";
            for (int j=0; j<array[0].length;j++ ) {
                output += array[i][j]+", ";
            }
            output += "\n";
        }

        return output += "]";
    }
```

I tried to rewrite such a thing in "Ruby functional Style", but I think there are still some improvements. Eg. I want to remove the mutable variable **output**

```
  def to_s
        output = "[\n"
        @data.each_with_index do |row,i|
            output << "Row #{i+1} : "
            row.each { |num| output << "#{num}," }
            output << "\n"
        end

        output+"]"
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you see the pattern:

1. initialize an accumulator (in your case `output`)
2. on each iteration of some collection modify the accumulator (in your case append to it)
3. return the accumulator

that's a `fold`, or in Ruby terms an `inject`.

Actually, that's a bit of a tautology. A `fold` is a universal method of iteration: *everything* that can be expressed by iterating over the elements of a collection can also be expressed as a `fold` over the collection. In other words: *all* methods on `Enumerable` (including `each`!) could also be defined in terms of `inject` as the primitive method instead of `each`.

Think about it this way: a collection can either be empty or there can be a current element.  There's no third option, if you cover those two cases, then you have covered everything. Well, `fold` takes two arguments: one which tells it what to do when the collection is empty, and one which tells it what to do with the current element. Or, put yet another way: you can see a collection as a series of instructions and `fold` is an interpreter for those instructions. There are only two kinds of instructions: the `END` instruction and a `VALUE(el)` instruction. And you can supply the interpreter code for both those instructions to the `fold`.

In Ruby, the second argument is not part of the argument list, it is the block.

So, what's it look like as a `fold`?

```
def to_s
  @data.each_with_index.inject("[\n") do |acc, (row, i)|
    acc + "Row #{i+1} : #{row.join(',')}\n"
  end + ']'
end
```

If you're curious about whether or not the `each_with_index` may infect your code with some non-functional impurity, rest assured that you can just as easily get rid of it by including the index in the accumulator:

```
def to_s
  @data.inject(["[\n", 1]) do |(s, i), row|
    [s + "Row #{i} : #{row.join(',')}\n", i+1]
  end.first + ']'
end
```

Also note that in the first case, *with* the `each_with_index`, we're not actually doing anything "interesting" with the accumulator, unlike the second case, where we are using it to keep count of the index. In fact, the first case is actually a restricted form of `fold`, it doesn't use all of its power. It really is just a `map`:

```
def to_s
  "[\n" + @data.map.with_index(1) do |row, i|
    "Row #{i} : #{row.join(',')}\n"
  end.join + ']'
end
```

In my personal opinion, it would actually be perfectly okay to use (mutable) string appending here instead of string concatenation:

```
def to_s
  "[\n" << @data.map.with_index(1) do |row, i|
    "Row #{i} : #{row.join(',')}\n"
  end.join << ']'
end
```

This saves us from creating a couple of unnecessary string objects, but more importantly: it is more idiomatic. The real problem is *shared* mutable state, but we're not sharing our mutable string here: when `to_s` returns its caller *does* get access to the string, but `to_s` itself has returned and thus no longer has access to it.

If you want to get real fancy, you could even use string interpolation:

```
def to_s
  %Q<[\n#{@data.map.with_index(1) do |row, i|
    "Row #{i} : #{row.join(',')}\n"
  end.join}]>
end
```

Unfortunately, this not only breaks IRb's syntax highlighting, but also my brain's ;-)

Comment: Hmm, I was seriously considering to propose your last example... By the way `with_index` (from enumerator) takes an offset parameter.

Comment: @steenslag: Didn't know that! You learn something new every day, even by teaching.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for your detail answer :) But I don't understand how can we know the order of "parameters" between the |..| of block when we chains the Enumerators.

Comment: I have checked out the doc http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-each_with_index, `each_with_index` & `with_index`, it writes `(*args), idx`, does it means when you chain other enumerators with `each_with_index` & `with_index`, they will add an index as the last parameter in |...|

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method with no mutable vars:

```
def to_s
  (
    [ "[" ] +
    @data.map.with_index { |row,i| "Row #{i+1} : #{row * ','}" } +
    [ "]" ]
  ).join("\n")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

same thing but shorter with less blocks.

```
  def to_s
        output = "[\n"
        @data.each_with_index do |row,i|
            output << "Row #{i+1} : #{row.join(',')}\n"
        end

        output+"]"
    end
```

Comment: `<<` is not _functional_.  You're still using mutable vars.

Comment: quote: "same thing but shorter"

Comment: "I tried to rewrite such a thing in "Ruby functional Style", but I think there are still some improvements. Eg. I want to remove the mutable variable output"

Comment: I don't realize i cannot use join, but thanks for your answer :)